# Rails collection_check_boxes labels not working within jquery modal

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

The below code is within a partial that has working click-handling between labels and checkboxes when loaded normally, though when this partial is loaded within a jQuery modal, clicking the label does not check the check-box.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:some_method, [some_array_of_strings], :to_s, Proc.new{|l| [some_array_of_strings][l]}, include_hidden: false) do |b| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%=  b.label(class: "checkbox-inline"){ b.check_box + b.text } %>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Produces this HTML

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="method_string_element_l">
  <input value="l" name="method[string_element][]" id="method_string_element_l" type="checkbox">l
</label>
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Are there errors? What other scripts could be messing with this code? What data is being passed when loading it in the modal?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix with some more HTML knowledge.

```
label for='method_string_element_1'
```

did not match to

```
name='method[string_element][]'
```

Since I have the label wrapping the checkbox I was able to pass for as nil

```
<%=  b.label(class: "checkbox-inline", for: nil){ b.check_box + b.text } %>
```

And receive this working HTML